# Webmethods Stored Procedure adapter return array

Tags: java, oracle, webmethods

I have some process that need to return array from stored procedure in oracle.
But i wanna do that via Stored Procedure adapter in webmethods adapter.
I dont know how to return array and pass it through webmethods adapter.

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

***** This is a comment as I cannot comment on posts I am putting it in answers section.***

There is a post in techcommunity softwareag. Check the below link. 
http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/40710.page

There is no varchar array type available from a adapter service but this can be done by writing custom java code using the same jdbc connection object created at IS level. **Again the varchar Array is completely depended on target database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "array" but typically a stored procedure returns a result set.

In this case, when you configure your JDBC Store Procedure Adapter, you will have a ResultSet tab in which you have to give a name to your result set and declare the fields that you expect to have in a record of your resultset.

[image]

As shown in the screenshot below, the stored procedure result set becomes a document list. See the input/output tab of the adapter like in the screenshot below. Each record in your result set becomes an item of the document list.

[image]

Note: After setting the ResultSet tab of the adapter, you won't see the changes immediately in the Input/Output tab of the adapter. You need "refresh" the adapter view by closing the adapter and reopening it. The correct Input/Output signature of your adapter will then be displayed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: seems like this is what i looking for, but i still curious about what i should return from my stored procedure, do u have any clue or maybe some example?

Comment: Execute your stored proc in Oracle. If it returns a set of records then you'll obtain the set of records as a list of documents as shown in the example once you correctly configured the JDBC Store Procedure Adapter in webMethods. It's pretty straightforward.